# dynamixel wheel mode

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to put my dynamixel mx-64 servo motor into wheel mode like it says in step 1 of this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20joint%20torque%20controller can anyone explain to me how to put the motor into wheel mode on ubuntu?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211471/dynamixel-wheel-mode/) by [rmoncrief](https://answers.ros.org/users/22816/rmoncrief/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-06-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2016-02-11**:
Did u managed to apply torque control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I had the same problem, and I realised that putting the dynamixel in wheel mode is the same as setting CW angle and CCW angle to 0:

```
 rosrun dynamixel_driver set_servo_config.py 1 --cw-angle-limit=0 --ccw-angle-limit=0
```

"1" states for your motor ID. If you get the following message, then your motor is set to wheel mode:

```
Configuring Dynamixel motor with ID 1
Setting CW angle limit to 0
Setting CCW angle limit to 0
done
```

However, I found that there are some issues in this mode for AX-12A: for the range of angle values that are not available in standard mode, the velocity and load values are all wrong. Here are some values I get:

```
current load:  0.03515625
current vel =  0.79042471074
current load:  0.03515625
current vel =  0.79042471074
current load:  0.10546875
current vel =  0.37196456976
current load:  0.10546875
current vel =  0.37196456976
current load:  0.10546875
current vel =  0.37196456976
current load:  0.16796875
current vel =  0.0
current load:  0.16796875
current vel =  0.0
current load:  0.82421875
current vel =  -27.7229843399
current load:  0.82421875
current vel =  -27.7229843399
current load:  0.82421875
current vel =  -27.7229843399
current load:  0.50390625
current vel =  -7.96236657142
current load:  0.50390625
current vel =  -7.96236657142
current load:  0.50390625
current vel =  -7.96236657142
current load:  0.16796875
current vel =  0.0
current load:  0.16796875
current vel =  0.0
current load:  0.14453125
current vel =  0.13948671366
current load:  0.14453125
current vel =  0.13948671366
current load:  0.14453125
current vel =  0.13948671366
current load:  0.05078125
current vel =  0.6974335683
current load:  0.05078125
current vel =  0.6974335683
```

The range [0.03 0.05] for the load and [0.69 0.79] for the velocity are correct, but then they take unexpected values, such as 0.82 for the load and -27 for the velocity. Did anyone encountered such issue? I think the problem might be in the joint_position_controller.py file in the dynamixel_controller package, when state is defined with the function filter:

```
def process_motor_states(self, state_list):
        if self.running:
            state = filter(lambda state: state.id == self.motor_id, state_list.motor_states)
            if state:
                state = state[0]
                self.joint_state.motor_temps = [state.temperature]
                self.joint_state.goal_pos = self.raw_to_rad(state.goal, self.initial_position_raw, self.flipped, self.RADIANS_PER_ENCODER_TICK)
                self.joint_state.current_pos = self.raw_to_rad(state.position, self.initial_position_raw, self.flipped, self.RADIANS_PER_ENCODER_TICK)
                self.joint_state.error = state.error * self.RADIANS_PER_ENCODER_TICK
                self.joint_state.velocity = state.speed * self.VELOCITY_PER_TICK
                self.joint_state.load = state.load
                self.joint_state.is_moving = state.moving
                self.joint_state.header.stamp = rospy.Time.from_sec(state.timestamp)
                
                self.joint_state_pub.publish(self.joint_state)
```

I just cannot find any description of this filter function to look into it.

If anyone has an answer for this, it would be very helpful.

---

Originally posted by [roxane](https://answers.ros.org/users/25655/roxane/) with karma: 26 on 2016-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2016-02-11**:
I have the motors mounted in a robot arm, how can I check the initial values of CW angle and CCW angle, so I can set them  to (0,0) and then back to the original setup?